# add alt to imagecopy

Tags: php, alt

I am making ribbons for a gaming clan that show tournament achievements and more. My code for producing the image is the following...

```
<?php
// Image Variables
$image = imagecreatefrompng("ribbons/ribbonBack.png");
$rib1 = imagecreatefrompng("ribbons/oneYear.png");
// Turn off alpha blending and set alpha flag for png
imagealphablending($image, true);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
// Set ribbons
imagecopy($image, $rib1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95, 30);
// display ribbons
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($rib1);
?>
```

My question is, how do I add alt text to this so that when a user mouses over $rib1 it gives them an alt text explaining what that ribbon is? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Like Mike B said, the Alt text comes from the HTML, not the image source.  See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute

Answer (score 2):

You're outputting raw binary of the image. There is no html here thus no where to set an alt attribute. The solution would be to reference your script in the src attribute of an image tag:

```
<img src="ribbons.php" alt="Title" />
```

Comment: We are using phpBB for the forums the ribbons are going on. Right now, I have an htaccess file telling the forums to read the .php files as .png so the images are accessible to the selection tool for ranks. Where should I put this code? Append it to the end of the php file? Should I generate a new html document and change the htaccess? I really appreciate your help. Thank you!